# github loosing track of files

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository for a hobbyist game project I'm working on: https://github.com/TimInghamDempster/The-Hollow-Shield.  Recently the app won't commit or sync anymore.  Switching to power shell I was informed that the files weren't staged.  This seemed odd as they are files that already existed in the repository and were being modified, not new files.

I tried to fix this with: "commit -am 'some message'".  This seemed to work as it let me commit the files and push to github.  Browsing the repository on the web showed the correct versions of the files.

The other member of the team was also unable to commit for the same reason.  After my attempted fix he did a pull and got the latest version of the files.  At this point his copy of the repo appeared to be a version behind and think that the changes he had just pulled were his changes, needed committing, and the files were unstaged.

At this point he removed his copy and made a fresh clone of the repo which seems to be working fine.

I tried this as well but every file I modify becomes unstaged.  I suspect that if I try the same "git commit -am" as before I will get the same result and mess up the repo for everyone again.

The question is what is going on and how do I fix it?

I've tried googling without success, but since I don't know what the problem is it's possible I'm not searching for the right thing.  I could just create a completely new repo but I'd like to keep the history intact if at all possible.  I'd also like to understand the problem so I can avoid it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I think you have misunderstood the concept of staging.
You stage a new file to be included in the next commit with `git add <file>`, so far so good. When you have changed some file you need to stage the changes you want to include in the next commit (sometimes you may want split the changes in two commits) this can also be done with `git add <file>` (or `git add -i <file>` if you want split the change in more commits).

`git commit -am "..."` is just a shortcut for `git add .;git commit -m "..."`

In your case, nothing seems wrong, you may just need to catch up on the workflow in git, a short introduction can be found at http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: Oh I see, so there was something stopping the github app from committing which seems to be resolved now and when I saw red text in the git shell window I assumed that was the problem but it's actually just a normal step that I had missed.  Thanks.